# differentiation of polygons, having cross borders

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, 3d

I have point data set and I segmented the data into different planar objects. after that, using contouring (convex hull), I obtained the boundary points. Please assume all points relevant to one polygon lie on a single plane. 
since i need straight line segments for the boundary, i fit 3d line segments for boundary points. finally by intersecting 3d line segments, i derived the polygon boundary with straight edges (contouring boundary is also straight, but, contains with very small line segments. 
i want a generalized boundary. so i fitted series of line segments for the orderly arranged boundary points). Once I get the generalized boundary, some boundary lines cross some other polygon boundaries. this is not an error due to my process, it is due to way how contouring represent the point boundaries.

Now I want to know which polygon has cross boarders and which does not has cross borders. for example i want to differentiate polygon A from polygon B in the figure.

Hope my problem is clear to all..
Actually, I can not imagine a logic to do this. So, please help me to differentiate these two types of polygons. thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about what the question is, where are you stuck?

Comment: @Samuel Reid: Sorry for inconveniences. did the modification to original post. hope it is clear now. thanks